# Scale dataset while preserving relative distributions between columns

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-scaling

I have a large dataset with 460 columns. The columns have names such as

'AppOpen_1day', 'AppOpen_2day', ...... 'AppOpen_15day',

'Dig_Pos_1day', 'Dig_Pos_2day', ...... 'DigPos_15day'

etc. Each column belongs to one of 62 categories (for example, the first set of columns above belongs to the 'AppOpen' category, the next set belongs to the 'Dig_Pos' category).

Now, I need to scale these columns in order to train an autoencoder to fit on this dataset. I also need to make sure that the relative distributions between columns in a category doesn't change.

(for example, AppOpen_2day column's distribution will be slightly shifted to the right with higher mean and standard deviation compared to AppOpen_1day column's distribution. That's how the data is, and I want to preserve that).

I have tried sklearn's StandardScaler(), however it fits and scales each column independently, hence there is a good chance the relative distributions between columns in a category would change.

Is there a method to scale my dataset where that doesn't happen? Or any existing standard library function that does the same?

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas, you could apply your own standard scaling to each category:

1. Groups columns per category using [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) i.e., `"AppOpen"`, `"Dig_Pos"` and any other category you have. If you haven't already, create a new column that has the name of the category so you can groupby that.
2. Compute the mean and the standard deviation for each category using [`pandas.DataFrame.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.std`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.std.html) i.e., calculate `category_mean` and `category_std`.
3. Apply the transform on the grouped data: `(grouped_category_data - category_mean) / category_std`
4. Concatenate the scaled data for each category into a new dataframe.

Comment: Does it make sense to take the mean and std of a category of columns?

Instead can we use MinMaxScaler for this? I've read that it preserves the original distribution of the column...

Comment: @SacredMechanic yeah that would work too, basically you can put any transform you want in steps 2-3 of my answer. Instead of manually calculating you can using `sklearn.MinMaxScaler`. The key here is to group by the relevant categories and not scaling on the whole dataset!